# How to tap correct SKSpriteNode in automated test?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, automated-tests, skspritenode

How to tap the correct SKSpriteNode in my iOS game created in swift (XCode 7, SpriteKit)? Finding the node seems not to be the issue, since in the test, 'exists' returns true. When I change my test to "app.tap()" then it does work. Except I have multiple SKSpriteNodes, so this does not solve my problem.

Below you can find code snippets. I hope you can help me with my problem. Any suggestions/hints are welcome.

Code snippet from my SKScene:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    var newGameButton : SKSpriteNode!
    newGameButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button")
    newGameButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+5)
    newGameButton.size = CGSizeMake(200.0, 40.0)
    newGameButton.name = "newGame"
    newGameButton.isAccessibilityElement = true
    newGameButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
    newGameButton.accessibilityLabel = "newGame"
    self.addChild(newGameButton)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let nodes = self.nodesAtPoint(location)
    for  node in nodes {
        if (node.name == "newGame") {
            viewController.beginNewGame()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Current setup in UITest:

```
import XCTest

class MemoryPlayUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        XCUIApplication().launch()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testStartNewGame() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let newGameButton = app.otherElements["newGame"]
        XCTAssertEqual(newGameButton.label, "newGame")
        XCTAssertTrue(newGameButton.exists)
        newGameButton.tap()  
        ...{test logic to test if new game is started}
    }
}
```